# Performance with many items using Jquery

Tags: jquery, performance, loops

I'm using the following code to loop

```
$( ".eco_li" ).each( function( index, element ){

           var string_temp = $(this).find('.eco_a').html();


           if ((string_temp.toLowerCase().indexOf(key_words.toLowerCase()) < 0)) {

               $(this).css("display", "none");

           }else{
               $(this).css("display", "block");
           }

       });
```

**When there are 2000+ items with class eco_li, the speed will be very slow.** I need to display 4000+ items in the page and need to loop it. How to solve the performance issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe Pagination/Server side will be better, don't make such heavy manipulation on the client side

Comment: Thanks! I'll try server-side solution.

Comment: Or store data in array and use client side pagination/filtering